# paste command: setting (multiple) delimiters

Tags: text-processing, paste

In Linux, I have the following problem with `paste` from (GNU coreutils) 8.13:

Trying to set another delimiter than the default (TAB) results in either just printing the first character of the defined delimiter or perfectly ignoring it.

**Question**: *How does one define (multiple) delimiters when using* `paste`?

Simply using, e.g. *abc-123* as delimiter would be nice. With "multiple" I mean e.g. 2 TABS instead of one.

---

The patterns enclosing the delimiter(s) I've tried so far were

- `--delimiters="\delimiter"`
- `--delimiters='\delimiter'`
- `--delimiters=$"\delimiter"`
- `--delimiters=$'\delimiter'`

All with the same result: Only the first character is accepted or perfectly ignored. I've also tried the short version `-d"\"` and multiple instances &ndahs; nothing.

Also:

- `--delimiters="\\"` → Error message

What works perfectly, though not what I want:

- `--delimiters="\n"` → newline
- `--delimiters="\0"` → nothing inbetween
- `--delimiters="\t"`→ <kbd>TAB</kbd>, the default. Great.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To have `abc` inbetween file1 and file2, you can do:

```
paste -d abc file1 /dev/null /dev/null file2
```

Or:

```
paste -d abc file1 - - file2 < /dev/null
```

If you want two tabs:

```
paste file1 /dev/null file2
```

Comment: "*using `/dev/null` to create two columns in text processing*" works (besides: is this common knowledge I've missed so far and if not: where did you get this information from?)

Comment: @Chirp.NotLuke. `/dev/null` acts like an empty file when reading, so you're pasting `file1`, and empty file, and empty file, file2 with separators being, in turn, `a`, `b` and `c`. Details on how `-d` works are in the `paste` man page.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas can you also add `pr -mts'abc' file1 file2` as alternative?

Answer (score 4):

It's because you are giving it only two files to join, each character of delimiter string is used between each join of lines from each of the input files.

eg

```
file1 line1 DELIMCHAR0 file2 line1 DELIMECHAR1 file3 line1 ...
file1 line2 DELIMCHAR0 file2 line2 DELIMECHAR1 file3 line2 ...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

On BSD systems (not Linux to my knowledge), there is the `lam` (as in “laminate”) utility, which is faster and shorter than the above solution:

```
lam file1 -s delimiter file2
```